# JavaSE-1.6 and JavaEE compatibility

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am currently designing a SDK that is intended to be used in both desktop and web applications. Currently I have been developing this SDK in using the JavaSE-1.6 Library and utilizing the Apache HttpComponents library as well as the JibX Library for web connections and xml parsing respectively.

If I wish to develop a web application using the JavaEE library, would I be able to use the SDK that I have developed in JSE-1.6?

If so, are there any compatibility issues that I need to be aware of?

If not, would it be better to develop the SDK in JavaEE, or would I run into the same compatibility problems if I wished to create a desktop application?

Comment: J2EE is not current any more. Use JavaEE. Use Java SE 7.

Comment: I have read this twice, and still don't get it. What do you mean by "JavaSE-1.6 library" and "J2EE library"? If what you are asking about is dependency management, I think you should take a look at maven (http://maven.apache.org/) or ivy (http://ant.apache.org/ivy/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J2EE/Java EE is not mutually exclusive from Java SE as you seemed to expect, given the question. Instead, Java EE **requires** Java SE to run. So if you just design your API to be compatible with Java SE, then it'll work equally fine on Java EE.

As to the version compatibility, checkout [Wikipedia on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition). For example, the current Java EE 6 requires a minimum of Java SE 1.6.